# ajax json php decode

Tags: javascript, php, json

i'm looking for passing params between server and client but i don't find a solution. I've read all the web but i don't find a working solution.

Client Side

```
function move(column, line) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php?action=setpawn',
    data: {column: column, line: line},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.donnees);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown+textStatus);
    }
});
}
```

Server Side

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
header('Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8');
$response = array('isvalid' => "0" , 'donnees' => $data['column']);
echo json_encode($response);
```

I can't acces 'column' and 'line' data on the server, and the json response is bad too (sometimes parse error or bad result).

Please help me i can't find a way to make it work... 
(sorry for my bad english, i'm french and i do the best i can)

Comment: What is in `$_POST['column']` and `$_POST['line']`?

Comment: You've read all the web? Wow.

Comment: agree with Jay...you should access the info that way. I've never seen the file_get_contents being used in conjunction with a POST request unless for an uploaded file

Comment: i don't know because i can't pass $_POST['column'] in the json respons without a parse error.

Comment: i've tried $_POST['column'] but it seems to be the same result, i've got a parse error with this solution too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery does not JSON-encode by default, but as `x-www-form-urlencoded`. You need to send

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php?action=setpawn',
    data: JSON.stringify({column: column, line: line}),
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
})
```

Check at the server side whether `file_get_contents('php://input')` is what you expect, before `json_decode`ing it and getting a parse error.

Comment: great answer, thanks you a lot! when you say that i have to check the content at the server side before decode, what I have to do, I don't understand. I have to check the string received that's is?

Comment: Well, I'm just saying that when you get a parse error you should debug by looking at the raw input.